# i have a problem with creating new data in mongoose as i always get code 11000

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a login page with mongoose and when i try to submit a new user it gives me the error code 11000 her is my code for the schema

```js
const mongo = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongo.Schema({
    stuName: {
        type: String,
        requierd: true, 
         
    },
    stuID: { 
        type: String, 
        requierd: true, 
        unique: true 
    },
    password: { 
        type: String, 
        requierd: true 
    },
    Ua: { 
        type: String, 
        requierd: true, 
        
    },
    adminCode: { 
        type: String, 
        requierd: true, 
         
    }

}, { collection: "users" })


const Model = mongo.model("userSchema", userSchema)
module.exports = Model
```

and here is my code for the bost method

```js
app.post("/sginUp", async(req, res) => {
    Userdb.init()
    console.log(req.body)
    const hashPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password ,10)
    const user = new Userdb ({
        stuName : req.body.stuName,
        stuID : req.body.stuID,
        password : hashPass ,
        Ua : req.body.Ua,
        adminCode: req.body.adminCode
    })
    console.log(user)
    
    try { 
         await user.save()  
        console.log(`user creted successfuly : ${user}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.json({status:'error'})
    }
})
```

and that is the error it gives me

```js
{
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { userName: 1 },
  keyValue: { userName: null }
}
```

i have read a lot of answers and nothing have helped me so far

Comment: Code 11000 means duplicate. Surely you're trying to insert a document with a duplicate index? Also `requierd` --> `required`

Comment: I'm not I add it once then it refuses to add more

Comment: Yes, that's what duplicate means :) If you insert it once, then try to add the same object again, of course you won't be able to.

Comment: I don't add the same user again i try to register new one